# Is there a way to curve an element?

Tags: html, three.js, webgl

is there a way (probably with webGL, maybe also with three.js) to curve an html element inwards? (So it looks like the new panoramic samsung TV, for example).

Just to be clear - I do not want to create a curved plane and use an image as a texture. It's a dynamic div - a video player, with an interactive skin to be exact, and I want to curved inward)

THANKS! :)

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by inward curve ? A picture or something ?

Comment: No, There is no way to curve an HTML element as of 2016/2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a direct way , but here is a hack with `:before` and `:after` pseudo element to achieve an inward curve.

```css
#video-player {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
#video-player:after,
#video-player:before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  content: " ";
}
#video-player:after {
  top: 120px;
  left: -100px;
}
#video-player:before {
  top: -120px;
  left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="video-player">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not at all what I meant... :)
I don't want to curve the div of the player. I want the *whole* player widget to be deformed inwards - skin, top buttons... everything.
(As if I created a curved plane with webGL and used the player as texture)

Comment: This doesn't work if you change `<div>` to `<video>` nor `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: No, you can not curve an HTML element as of 2016/2

You said you didn't want to do this but, you could try rendering a curved plane video and your UI curved with it in WebGL (or three.js) all manually implemented (not using HTML elements). [There's an example of video in three.js here](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_video.html)

The biggest obstacle will be that currently getting video into WebGL is somewhat heavy. Video larger than a certain size might run too slow.