# A way to curve (outside) an element in CSS3

Tags: css, curve

I'm trying to curve an element and then add a `background-image` property in it.
I was looking on this question - [Is there a way to curve an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358684/is-there-a-way-to-curve-an-element). The only difference, is that I want it to be curved *outside*.

Here's an example:

[image: Example of curved-outside image]

This is what I tried to do: http://jsfiddle.net/KcmfC/1148/

The problem in this result is that it's too much curved. I can't find any solution for this.

```css
#test {
  background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg') repeat center center / cover;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 15em;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing I did is a bit tricky, I stretched the `width` to 140% and the I "cut" the edges via `overflow: hidden`. Here's my full example:

```css
#test {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height:  150px;
}
#test:before {
    background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg') repeat center center / 1048px 319px;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    content: "";
    width: 140%;
      height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: -20%;
    right: -20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div>
 SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo element

```css
div {
  background: gray url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg) no-repeat center bottom -25px / cover;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;      
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  background: gray url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg) no-repeat center bottom / cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: calc(100% - 25px);
  left:0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I didn't like the idea of loading the same image twice, and the corners doesn't look like what I was trying to do

Comment: @EliyaCohen The image corner can easily be cut by set the pseudo's width slightly bigger ... and you don't load image twice, it is in the cache and gets reused

Comment: Yea I know I can do that, look at my answer. Can you give a feedback? I'll be happy :)

Comment: @EliyaCohen That works just beautifully... +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

reduice the `border radius` pourentage

```css
body{
  margin:0
    }

#test {
    background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg') repeat center center / cover;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 15em;
    border-radius: 0 0 35% 35%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: This is still too much radius. I need really little just like the image example I gave.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```css
#test {
  background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg') repeat center center / cover;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 15em;
  border-radius: 0 0 70% 70% / 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't think of this approach, but your solution is a little bit problematic for my question. as you can see in the edges, It doesn't looks exactly like I wanted.